# you leave your money longer

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Woman: Hi. I'd like to open up a bank account.

Teller: What sort of account do you want, a checking account or a savings account?

Woman: What difference does it make?

Teller: A checking account is an  account you just write checks on.

Woman: And the savings account?

Teller: With the savings account, you **leave** your money longer and you can earn interest.

---

What does "you **leave** your money longer" mean?

Comment: What do _you_ think it might mean?

Comment: When you **save** money, you let it stay in the bank for a longer time instead of spending it, so it is there for an emergency or to buy something special. The bank rewards you for doing this by paying interest.

Comment: Thank you, Kate. I want to know what does "leave" exactly mean in this sentence.

Comment: Sometimes you agree to leave the money for minimum length of time (say one year) to get a better rate of interest. So you leave the money in the account without taking any of it out, for a year. Please see [**leave**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/leave): **2** Allow or cause to remain. Or **3.3** Deposit or entrust to be kept, collected, or attended to.

Comment: "An account you just write checks on" is a somewhat incorrect, and certainly confusing way to describe a checking account if you don't know what "a checking account is" you probably don't know what a check is.   I'm still curious. What is the exact source of this dialog?

Answer (score 1):

One meaning of "[leave](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave)" is to not take something with you: "I'll just *leave* my bag here." "I *left* my bag on the train."

You put money into a bank account. You take money out of a bank account. In the time between when you put it in and when you take it out, we can say you *leave* the money in the account, because you aren't taking it yet.

"Longer" means: for more time. People usually let more time pass before they take the money out, if the money is in a savings account, than they do if it's in a checking account.